# How do I distribute JSON-RPC requests to backends?

Tags: api-gateway, json-rpc

Good day to all!
Try to decipher the question more extensively.
JSON RPC requests come from users in the form:

```
{
"" json rpc ":" 2.0 ",
"method": "abc.new",
"id": 423,
"params": {
"card": {
"pan": "9342309420",
"expiry": "4234"
}
}
}
```

and depending on the incoming requests, they need to be distributed among the backends.
What tool and how can you achieve this?
Thanks in advance for your reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. This can be done using nginx+lua. but to be even more precise, using openresty. maybe it will be useful to someone

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to explain how you used nginx+lua and openresty to solve the problem in your question, so that your answer is useful to other users with similar issues.